# Store regular expression in search & replace window of visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

is there a possibility to store frequently used regular expressions (e.g. for search & replace) in Visual Studio. Except of the search history, i did not find any other option.

Thanks

Comment: Add a text file to your solution or project. Use it to store the search and replace strings.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: yeah this is currently the way to go but i wonder if there is a better solution